# WebUI access for workers in spark

Tags: apache-spark, docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

We have a cluster which is built by docker swarm 
Cluster consists of 1 Manager 3 Worker nodes.

it can be seen as follow:
[image]

and we have run Apache Spark on the cluster. It consists of a master and four workers. It is seen as follow on master web ui

[image]

The problem is that I can not access the details of worker node. It wants to connect to an ip(10.0.0.5:8081). But I can not access the link from my local machine.

[image]

Comment: which tool do you use to see your cluster?

Comment: Docker swarm visualizer

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind the port of the spark webui service and access the webui using localhost:8081 (if you are binding the localport 8081)
example in docker-compose.yml file
in the spark webui service put something like this
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports

the ip you specified(10.0.0.5) is the subnet created by docker you cannot access using that ip from your machine

Comment: I see but I have a lot of workers. How can I assign different ports

Comment: you have deployed your application in swarm do `docker service ls` to see the services that are linked to your local machine port.don't worry about the way you need to connect with the worker the docker will do those works

Comment: I am using docker compose file like 
 taht https://gist.github.com/sopaoglu/40785b1df86e438faf1fafc3304bd231, however I can not solve the problem

Comment: thanks for sharing your docker-compose file,see you are hitting the port 8081 that is not binded with any of the containers,i find spark master is using 7077 port i don't find that port in the compose file,what is want you to do is get into the container of both master and worker and do a curl command for example if `curl localhost:7077` is giving a 200 response bind the 7077 port line "7077:7007" ---> "machine-port:container-port" in the respective services

Comment: I guess you are just missing the port-binding. Here is a simple example on creating a 3 node cluster using docker-compose. This is the link : https://bigdatagurus.wordpress.com/2017/03/01/how-to-start-spark-cluster-in-minutes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, each docker has its own I.P too. You can try connecting to those. That may help determine where actually the problem is, weather its in Spark or Docker. Here is how you get the containter I.P : $ docker inspect <container_id> | grep -i ipaddress