# How to access the Spark worker job page?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, bitnami

I have a local k3s Kubernetes created by Rancher Desktop.

I installed Spark by

```
helm upgrade \
  spark \
  spark \
  --install \
  --repo=https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami \
  --namespace=hm-spark \
  --create-namespace
```

```
➜ kubectl get services -n hm-spark
NAME                                                  TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
spark-headless                                        ClusterIP   None            <none>        <none>                       32h
spark-master-svc                                      ClusterIP   10.43.200.139   <none>        7077/TCP,80/TCP              32h

➜ kubectl get pods -n hm-spark
NAME                                              READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
spark-master-0                                    1/1     Running     0          32h
spark-worker-0                                    1/1     Running     0          32h
spark-worker-1                                    1/1     Running     0          32h
```

Currently I am doing `port-forward`

```
➜ kubectl port-forward service/spark-master-svc --namespace=hm-spark 4040:80
```

to access the Spark master UI at http://localhost:4040/

However, I won't be able to open Spark worker job pages as they are using Kubernentes internal cluster IP.

[image]

Here is this chart values: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/main/bitnami/spark/values.yaml

Is there any value I can set to help me access the Spark worker job page? Thanks!

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46830018/webui-access-for-workers-in-spark) deployed by Docker Swarm but also has no accepted answers.

Comment: Is there a specific reason not to use [Spark Operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator)? Specifically, Kubernetes doesn't need a Spark master. Or standalone worker pods. All you really need is the history server

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks, when I checked before, I thought that is for Google Cloud only. I will try it and report back!

Comment: Nope! I've seen people use it on Azure and AWS clusters. Not sure about k3s since you'll need admission webhook controller as well

Comment: Hmm, for Spark Operator, I met another issue and posted at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/1735 If I figured either, I will post back. 

Comment: As mentioned, k3s might not work. You may need to use minikube. And your instructions there are wrong. `https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami` repo has nothing to do with that project

Comment: @OneCricketeer Spark helm chart from Bitnami works well in the k3s cluster on my M1 MacBook, but Spark Operator not. Thanks for reminding! I have fixed the shell commands which was a mistake in the [ticket](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/1735) in Spark Operator.

Comment: The operator requires the webhook admission controller. Have you enabled that? Could you simply try minikube?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the related document at https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/spark#configuring-spark-master-as-reverse-proxy

In my case I am using Cloudflare Tunnel. So I don't need `ingress` related part in the doc.

Here is my step:

1. Point `http://spark-master-svc.hm-spark.svc:80` to `spark.mydomain.com` in my Cloudflare Tunnel.
2. Deploy Spark by

```bash
helm upgrade \
  spark \
  spark \
  --install \
  --repo=https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami \
  --namespace=hm-spark \
  --create-namespace \
  --values=my-values.yaml
```

**my-values.yaml**

```yaml
master:
  configOptions:
    -Dspark.ui.reverseProxy=true
    -Dspark.ui.reverseProxyUrl=https://spark.mydomain.com
worker:
  configOptions:
    -Dspark.ui.reverseProxy=true
    -Dspark.ui.reverseProxyUrl=https://spark.mydomain.com
```

Now I am able to visit both master and worker pages!

[image]

[image]